# Getting mmc_block to display more than 8 partitions

Tags: linux, partition, block-device, flash-memory

When you format an SD card or a USB drive with the Chromebook Recovery Utility, it creates twelve partitions. It also leaves the rest of the memory unallocated. I want to be able to use this space as normal memory, which would require the partitions higher than 7 to be exposed in `/dev`. However, trying to load `mmc_block` with a parameter value other than `8` doesn't actually load it with that parameter. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

In the linux kernel config, set CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_MINORS to 13 or add `mmcblk.perdev_minors=13` to your cmdline.

See https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt